# PHP PCRE - match different subpattern name depending on context

Tags: php, regex, pcre

As the title states, I started thinking about how to match, for example, 2 different subpatterns in a regex applied on a string, on the condition that if the content has only numbers it will be assigned the subpattern name `<id>`, otherwise (letters or letters + numbers) assigned as `<action>`. The context is a PHP router class I'm writting out.

This is a portion of the condition used to match an action containing words :

`(?P<action>[\w]+)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Give more information about how the input strings can look like

Comment: So, `(?P<id>[\d]+)|(?P<action>[\w]+)`?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes, I shall try that (I assumed it required magic)

Comment: @Wrikken sorry for the delay, if you post your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Wrikken Could you write an answer :) ?

Comment: @HamZa: wow, blast from the past... But yeah, let's clean up the unanswered questions ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make 2 subpatterns & OR them (`|`):

```
(?P<id>[\d]+)|(?P<action>[\w]+)
```